# C++ Makefile config with Debug mode

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I've been trying to configure a simple makefile and I've got it working for a single file `main.ccp`. What I'm trying to accomplish is have every source file generate an object file in either `bin/rel/obj` or `bin/deb/obj`, standard and debug mode. However I don't want to type out these instructions for every new file I add in the source. **Is there a way to have this setup work, but for all files inside the src dir?**. I have been at this for a while now and can't seem to get it right.

```
# GNU make 4.3 for Win32

# compiler
CXX=g++

# base directories
SRC=./src/
BIN=./bin/rel/

# standard compiler flags 
CXXFLAGS= -Wall -std=c++17

# debug mode arguments
debug: BIN=./bin/deb/
debug: CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g

# object directory inside the rel or deb directory
OBJ=$(BIN)obj/

# build main depending on main.o
main: main.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJ)main.o -o $(BIN)main

# build main.o into the target bin dir
main.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(SRC)main.cpp -o $(BIN)main.o

# debug target
debug: main.o main
```

*file tree*
[image: current file tree]

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: Yes, you can store a list of the source files in a variable with `ls *.cpp`. The target `main` should use the list as dependencies. An example with a manual list: https://courses.cs.duke.edu/cps108/doc/makefileinfo/sample.html

Comment: Better than `ls *.cpp` is to use GNU make's `wildcard` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want to do using target-specific variables.  The manual is very clear that the values of target-specific variables are *only* available in recipes.  They are not available in targets and prerequisites.  That's because until make actually tries to walk the dependency graph and build things it has no idea what the target-specific variables should be, and it can't walk the dependency graph until after it builds the dependency graph and the nodes in the graph are the targets and prerequisites to be built... catch-22.

The simplest way to do it is with a recursive make invocation.  For example set the "standard" builds to be `rel` then if `debug` is run, invoke make recursively overriding the value:

```
BIN = ./bin/rel/

# standard compiler flags
CXXFLAGS_DBG =
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 $(CXXFLAGS_DBG)

...the rest of the makefile here...

# debug mode
debug:
        $(MAKE) BIN=./bin/deb/ CXXFLAGS_DBG='-DDEBUG -g'
```

Of course there are other ways to do it but a recursive invocation is the most straightforward.